# RecyclerView parallax scroll background for each item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, parallax

I am trying to get a parallax effect working. Such as in the sound cloud android app or something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfOuWpPkA6Q). 
I have a `RecyclerView` where every list item has a `FrameLayout` and an `ImageView` in it and I need every background image in the `RecyclerView` to be parallaxed.

```
public class MyRecyclerView {

    private static final Dictionary<Integer, Integer> listViewItemHeights = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();

    ...

}
```

... and in the onBindViewHolder method I have added this:

```
...

viewHolder.scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {


        private int getScroll() {
            View c = discountSectionLayoutManager.getChildAt(0); 
            int scrollY = -c.getTop();

            listViewItemHeights.put(discountSectionLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition(), c.getHeight());
                for (int i = 0; i < discountSectionLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition(); ++i) {
                    if (listViewItemHeights.get(i) != null) 
                        scrollY += listViewItemHeights.get(i); //add all heights of the views that are gone
                }
                return scrollY;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
             int scrollY = - getScroll();
             viewHolder.imageFrameLayout.setTranslationY(scrollY * 0.1f);
        }


}
```

The problem with this is that EVERY item will scroll up, and not just the ones that are visible. My `RecyclerView` is large with many items, and the items at the bottom will be all scrolled up as well. (for example if I can see item 1-3 and scroll down, even items 4-15 will scroll right as now). Maybe the `getScroll()` method can be modified somehow to only only scroll the background of the visible items?

Comment: DId you ever manage to get parallax working on items in your RecyclerView?